# keep gettin this error with json using python for discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    with open("users.json", 'r') as f:
        user = json.load(f)



        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author.channel)


        with open('user.json', w) as f:
            json.dump(users, f)
```

Error:

```
 line 40, in on_message
    with open("users.json", 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'users.json'
```

Comment: and if you run `ls` in the directory this script is running from, you see it?

Comment: yes I'm getting the same error every where the bot log in fine with no error but when I try to type give back that error

Comment: Try adding `import os; print(os.listdir())` before the `open` line.  That should give you a list of all the files in the working directory.  `user.json` probably isn't in that list. You can use `os.getcwd()` to get the current working directory of the python script, which will tell you where it is looking for the files.

Comment: I added it but its giving me an invalid syntax